# How to overlay div over other div's contents without being in that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making something and am wondering how to get a div to overlay another div and it's contents. What I am trying to do it kinda like youtube, when you are on a video and you hover over someone's avatar it will show a small box with their channel art and things. Here is a photo of what i'm currently getting [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/3te4an). Here are my codes for the two divs:
**circular div**

```
#staff-info {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #999;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

**staff boxes**

```
#staff {
    width: 256px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 7px 4px 7px 4px;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f3f6f9;
}
.staff-avatar {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.staff-name {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
.staff-job {
    padding-top: -100px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

**Grey area (main div)**

```
#youtuber-about {
    width: 890px;
    height: auto;
    background: #d5d3d3;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**html for the divs**

```
<div id="staff-info">yolo</div>
        <div id="youtuber-about" style="color: #333;">Our Staff<br>
            <?php
            foreach ($staff as $staff) {
                echo '
                <div id="staff"><img src="'.$staff['avatar'].'" class="staff-avatar"><div class="staff-name">'.$staff['name'].'</div><div class="staff-job">'.$staff['job'].'</div></div>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can use tooltip. Something like this http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

Comment: To use that you need to download their source, I don't want to use any sources like that for my project, thanks for answering tho

Comment: Tried `data-*` attributes within `html` of `circular`, `staff`, `grey`, etc. , `:hover` `data(attr)` within `css` ?

Comment: ok, see it - http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-create-a-tooltips-with-jquery/

Comment: try to use javascript, you add a function in your tag as a "onmouseover="here goes your function" and also  onmouseout="your function", the last is optional.

Comment: @guest271314 no but if I have position:absolute; it will put the div over the content like this http://prntscr.com/3teag5, but how would I get it to go above the little box for the user, and change it with javascript for each user?

Comment: @user3388636 i'll try what you posted, see if it works

Comment: @TheRadGamerDan Should be possible with adjustments of `top` and `left`. Perhaps other solution could be to utilize `:before` and `:after` `pseudo` elements with above approach, instead of "overlay" `div` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can just append the info `div` inside of each staff member `div` whenever the users moves their mouse over that staff member.

```
 $('#youtuber-about > div').mouseover(function(){
     $(this).append($('#info'));
 });
```

And then you can style that with CSS quite easily, just setting the info `div` to be `position: absolute;` and set to fill the containing element, set to show on hover.

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6TPsC/2/)

Comment: Ok so this looks good, but, what if you were to have a php foreach there so it's echoing more than one.

Comment: This is why I made 3 image containers in my demo. That is to simulate the output of a `foreach` loop creating multiple containers. Notice that there is only one info `div` that is used for all three images.

Comment: So I got it to work on my project nicely, now just gotta make it so each staff has a separate info box, should be easy

Comment: If each staff has a separate info box, couldn't you just put each info box inside of each staff box to start with, and skip the javascript completely?

Comment: I could, but it wouldn't really look as good as having it overlay with the info.

Answer (score 0):

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

What I would do is have a div that holds both of these two divs and play with your CSS and the nesting of the divs to overlay them properly.

Absolute and Relative positioning is pretty tricky as first but once you get a hang of it you'll be doing it left and right

So remember

Add both divs to a third empty div and then put the one you want overlaying below the other.

To move use

```
.something {
position: absolute
top:20%
right:15%
left:10%
bottom:20%
}
```